# mocking a jackson object used locally in a method

Tags: java, junit, jackson

I have a method which deserializes my POJO using jackson.

My class looks like this:

```
@Builder
public class MyCustomClass {
...
...
...
}
```

My decode method looks something like this:

```
public MyCustomClass decodeObject(String jsonString) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    MyCustomClass object = mapper.readValue(jsonString, MyCustomClass.class);

    return object;
}
```

I am writing a unit test method to test the decode method. How can I mock the objectMapper object? I was looking at InjectMocks, but I was unsure how exactly to be doing it. 
Is there a specific way to do it using InjectMocks? Also, is InjectMocks the correct way to mock local variables?

Answer (score 1):

change your class to this:

```
class MyClass{
   ObjectMapper mapper;
   MyClass(ObjectMapper mapper) {
      this.mapper = mapper;
   }

   public MyCustomClass decodeObject(String jsonString) {
      MyCustomClass object = mapper.readValue(jsonString, MyCustomClass.class);

      return object;
  }
}
```

then you can inject a mock of the object Mapper into your class.

The idea behind is that *object creation* for dependencies is not a responsibility of the Business class.